# Create nested Obj in JS

Tags: javascript

I have an an array of objects that contains a bunch of entires, but I want to group together some of them dynamically.

My Object could look like this

```
[{
    Beton: "120"
    Asfalt: "80"
    ConstructionId: "(10)4"
    Name: "Pælefundamenter og brøndfundamenter"
    ParentId : "10" 
    ParentName: "Bygningsbasis, terræn"
}]
```

so now i want the object to look like this

```
[{
    ConstructionId: "(10)4"
    Name: "Pælefundamenter og brøndfundamenter"
    ParentId : "10" 
    ParentName: "Bygningsbasis, terræn"
    materialLifeTime: {
        Beton: "120",
        Asfalt: "80",
    }
}]
```

I have tried a bunch, but can't make it work.

Thank you so much,
Sillas

Comment: You can use `array.map(original => { target })` to map objects to a different result

Answer (score 0):

You can try this .

```js
const value = [{
Beton: "120",
Asfalt: "80",
ConstructionId: "(10)4",
Name: "Pælefundamenter og brøndfundamenter",
ParentId : "10" ,
ParentName: "Bygningsbasis, terræn"
}]

value[0].materialLifeTime = {
        Beton: "120",
        Asfalt: "80",
    }
    
console.log(value )
```

Comment: but the value in the other objects might differ, so I have to create it dynamically, the only entires that are given are: ConstructionId, NameParentId , ParentName. So the rest needs to go in that nestede Object.

Comment: value[0].materialLifeTime = {
        Beton: "120",
        Asfalt: "80",
    }

HERE { } , You can push the dynamic value if your property name is same .

Comment: property name is not the same, only for the: ConstructionId, NameParentId , ParentName. but not for the nested Object.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Tvde1 is right. You can do this.

```js
const materialLifeTime = [{
    Beton: "120",
    Asfalt: "80",
    ConstructionId: "(10)4",
    Name: "Pælefundamenter og brøndfundamenter",
    ParentId : "10" ,
    ParentName: "Bygningsbasis, terræn",
}]

const mainArrayObj = [{
    ConstructionId: "(10)4",
    Name: "Pælefundamenter og brøndfundamenter",
    ParentId : "10" ,
    ParentName: "Bygningsbasis, terræn",
}]

let modifiedArr = mainArrayObj.map(function(element){
   const newArr = [element, {materialLifeTime: materialLifeTime}];
     console.log(newArr);
});

let anotherWay = mainArrayObj.map(function(element){
   const newArr = [element, ...materialLifeTime];
     console.log(newArr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete()` to remove the keys from the original object

```js
const data = [{
    Beton: "120",
    Asfalt: "80",
    ConstructionId: "(10)4",
    Name: "Pælefundamenter og brøndfundamenter",
    ParentId : "10" ,
    ParentName: "Bygningsbasis, terræn"
}];

const keysToMove = [ 'Asfalt', 'Beton' ];

const res = data.map(d => {
  d.materialLifeTime = {};
  keysToMove.forEach(k => {
    d.materialLifeTime[k] = d[k];
    delete d[k]
  });
  return d;
})

console.log(res);
```